# How run a program in C for x minutes?

Tags: c, system, fork, sleep

I am trying to run a program in `C` for `x` minutes. I need to make the `child` process go to sleep for that amount of time. Any help would be appreciated. Basically I am trying to understand how `fork()` and `sleep()` work. Here is my code snippet

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int i = fork();
    printf("fork return value = %d\n", i);
    printf("this is the time before sleep");
    system("date +%a%b%d-%H:%M:%S");
    printf("\n");
    if (i==0){
        sleep(120);
    }
    system("ps");
    printf("this is the time after sleep");
    system("date +%a%b%d-%H:%M:%S");
    printf("\n");
}
```

Comment: Just a FYI -- sleep() isn't guaranteed to actually sleep as long as you ask for. It may be interrupted by a signal. If you really want to wait a certain amount of time, you should check sleep()'s return value. If there is time left in the sleep, the number of seconds is returned, and you can again request to sleep that much longer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

int main(void)
{
    pid_t pid;
    int rv=1;

    switch(pid = fork()) {
    case -1:
        perror("fork");  /* something went wrong */
        exit(1);         /* parent exits */

    case 0:
        printf(" CHILD: This is the child process!\n");
        printf(" CHILD: My PID is %d\n", getpid());
        printf(" CHILD: My parent's PID is %d\n", getppid());
        printf(" CHILD: I'm going to wait for 30 seconds \n");
        sleep(30);
        printf(" CHILD: I'm outta here!\n");
        exit(rv);

    default:
        printf("PARENT: This is the parent process!\n");
        printf("PARENT: My PID is %d\n", getpid());
        printf("PARENT: My child's PID is %d\n", pid);
        printf("PARENT: I'm now waiting for my child to exit()...\n");
        wait(&rv);
        printf("PARENT: I'm outta here!\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Say thanks to [Brian "Beej Jorgensen" Hall](http://beej.us/guide/bgipc/output/html/singlepage/bgipc.html)

Comment: What is rv in your code? I see that you define it as int, but I don't see where you assign any value to it. In other words I don't understand what exit(rv) does and what wait(&rv) does.

Comment: `rv` is the return value that the child is suppose to return to the parent. I failed to initialize it with some value. Done the same now! Thanks for pointing it out.